# Google Places Nearby Search requests returns different values intermittently

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been using Google Places API for [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) . I noticed one particular thing. Here's a block from one sample output.

```
geometry: Object
location: P
ob: 28.579
pb: 77.36831899999993
```

Do you notice the parameters `ob` and `pb`. I've noticed them to change quite regularly.
A few weeks back they were `jb` and `kb`. Then they became `lb` and `mb`. Now when I'm trying them out, they are `ob` and `pb`.

Although I've found a way around to use these values without referring them by their keys, but I'm still curious as to whether these key names hold any significance and why are they changing so frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the result of a minification process (which takes variables, function and property names and replaces them consistently in order to reduce the size of your scripts). Whenever something changes in the minification process (minifier code changes, javascript code changes, etc) there is a chance that the replaced name for a certain property is different than it was before.

Comment: I didn't understand. Size of scripts? But this is the response I'm getting after making a call to this method : `service.nearbySearch(request, callback);`

Comment: I think all or most of google's code in Javascript is run through the Google Closure Compiler which among other things does minification. This means that there is a good chance that the code that serves you the response is minified and those two properties of the response somehow got renamed by the compiler.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll wait for any other answer that might have a better explanation, else I'll accept this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule for Google Maps API, accessing data (like coordinates for example) is not done accessing the JavaScript objects directly, but querying the response.
This is a nearby search example from Google:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search
You should check how is it accessed in this snippet:

```
function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to parse the JSON result from the places autosuggest drop down.

To avoid this problem, you can call the lat and lng methods on the location object rather than attempt to use the fields by name.

Something like:

```
var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
```

Though it worth sharing.